# Why edit sugestion Rejected without any clear reason?

Tags: discussion, edits

This is only about this one particular post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6537333
here.
So as they (Reviewers) claims "JApplet Content Clears When Thread.sleep Used " is suitable as it is,  but to me it makes no sense, When I give the answer, I specially ask the question owner about the situation.

JApplet Content never hanged because of a Thread.sleep. It is very wrong to say that.  as I know a review mean make the questions more reliable and targeted to specific topic. I don't know how this goes with it. 
I like the forum very much and I have done this edit because someone will easily find the way in but seems it all was for nothing. I am not sure if this is  the right place for this discussion , Please move it If this in the wrong place.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The standard of English was better in the first version "the content of the applet not drawing anymore." is not grammatical  but you are saying your edit was more technically accurate?

Comment: Yes , I mean technically.  Because once after a  panel painted, it will never change unless we resize it or do something like that to make the frame repainted it self again. So  when this kind of loop used it will never painted , even for a bit. That is what I was tried to tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starters, the first version was more grammatically correct, so if you take away from that, then what you're adding has to be important for it to get approved.

Now, it's a bit difficult to tell whether what you're adding *is* important, because it seemingly comes from nowhere. I'm not familiar with applets, but that code there doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you changed the title and the question to, and the fact that you changed what the question is asking at all is grounds for rejection.

The way you explain it here makes it sound as if the questioner is misdiagnosing a problem that s/he is coming across. In that case, you should **comment** on the post with your reasoning rather than trying to edit the new question into the post, which will just confuse the asker.

Comment: okay, Thank you, "you should comment on the post with your reasoning rather than trying to edit the new question into the post, which will just confuse the asker." . I will follow this next time.